# Forward constructors to a member object

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, constructor

Is this a good approach to forward all constructors to a member data structure?

```
template<typename VectorData>
class VectorFunctionality
{
    VectorData data;
public:
    VectorFunctionality() = default;
    VectorFunctionality(const VectorFunctionality&) = default;
    template<typename ...Args>
    VectorFunctionality(Args... args) : data(std::forward<Args>(args)...) {};
};
```

VectorData can be std::array, std::vector etc.
VectorFunctionality inherits all of the VectorData c'tors.
This help to avoid write many c'tors in VectorFunctionality, other for std::array and other for std::vector.

Comment: if compiler supports C++11 constructor inheritance, maybe just use `private` inheritance, inherit in the constructors. disclaimer: i haven't tried that yet.

Comment: If you write it carelessly like that, then `std::is_constructible<VectorFunctionality, Args...>::value` is true for *any* choice of `Args...`, which may be undesirable.

Comment: also use `VectorFunctionality(Args&&... args)` to implicitly forward arguments. In the general case I don't think this gives a nice and simple API. The user won't easily understand the use of the constructor, unless you have a good documentation with it

Answer (score 1):

You have to be a little careful, as the variadic constructor can unintentionally match things you don't want it to.

Take the following (untested) piece of code:

```
VectorFunctionality<int> vf1;
VectorFunctionality<int> vf2(vf1); // Unintentionally calls the templated constructor
```

Given a non-const reference to a VectorFunctionality, the variadic constructor is a better match because it doesn't require a non-const to const conversion, so it is called instead of the copy constructor.

One way around this particular problem is to add another constructor, as in:

```
VectorFunctionality(VectorFunctionality& that) : VectorFunctionality(static_cast<VectorFunctionality const&>(that)) {}
```

Note: there are other manifestations of this issue (for instance, what if you have a instance that is derived from VectorFunctionality?).

Comment: Copy construction is never matched against a constructor template: the above code would call the [defaulted] copy constructor. Even if it would call the template constructor it would actually do the Right Thing, i.e., forward the call to the member.

Comment: A direct reference binding w/o derived-to-base conversion is an Exact Match, the cv-qualification doesn't matter. It's only relevant for comparing two reference bindings, which is not the case for the OP's ctor template. Here, we have two Exact Matches but one template and one non-template, hence the non-template is chosen.

Comment: @DietmarKühl *"Copy construction is never matched against a constructor template"* I'm not sure about that. A ctor template is never considered a copy- or move-ctor, but it can be chosen through overload resolution as a better match than the idiomatic copy-ctor taking a `const&` AFAIK. This requires that both take a reference. [Live example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2046bb2278ff6896)

Comment: You may use `const_cast` instead of `static_cast`.

Comment: @DyP: interesting. I always thought that you can't hijack copy construction with a templated constructor. It seems, the template constructor wouldn't inhibit the compiler from creating its own version but it doesn't mean that the copy constructor is always used for copying! Thank you very much for pointing this out!